# mk, sed, and embedding environment variables

Tags: sed, make, plan9

When using [mk](http://doc.cat-v.org/plan_9/4th_edition/papers/mkfiles), GNU sed, I find that variables do not expand at all.

Problematic code:

```
VAR=qux
...
build:
    sed -i "s|FOO = .*|FOO = $VAR|" bar.file
```

This seems to run the following:

```
sed -i "s|FOO = .*|FOO = $VAR|" bar.file
```

when I want it to run

```
sed -i "s|FOO = .*|FOO = qux|" bar.file
```

I have tried using single quotes and double quotes, as other stack exchange posts have mentioned. The only instance I can get `$VAR` to expand is when there are no quotes around it. Which of course means that `sed` no longer sees the expression as an expression.

Comment: If this is `bash` then put `set -x` before the `sed` call. That shows you what the shell executes.

Comment: "a problem that can't be reproduced and seemingly went away on its own (or went away when a typo was fixed)" -- This is not the case, the case was the quoting in my original. The quoting is not a form of typo as it was done intentionally. This problem caused me much strife and no help was available anywhere on the internet. This problem *is* reproducible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that, while I had previously tried escaping it, I erroneously put double quotes around it like so:

```
sed -i 's|FOO = .*|FOO = '"$VAR"'|' bar.file
```

Changing it to

```
sed -i 's|FOO = .*|FOO = '$VAR'|' bar.file
```

works.

Comment: It shouldn't work since the `sed` command is wrong. The middle `/` should be `|`.

Comment: Thanks, this was an error in the example I gave, not in the original code. I've corrected it.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a fragment in a Makefile.

There's two errors in the file:

1. The `sed` substitution command uses `|` as the delimiter, but the middle delimiter is `/`.
2. The Makefile variable `VAR` is dereferenced as `$VAR` instead of `$(VAR)` or `${VAR}`.

Note that a Makefile is not a shell script.  Therefore, the following Makefile is perfectly valid and will produce the string `qux world` as output on the terminal:

```
VAR=    qux                                        

build:                                             
        @echo 'hello world' | sed 's|hello|$(VAR)|'
```

---

In a Unix Makefile, `$VAR` would expand to the value of the variable `V` followed by the letters `AR`.  This is because unless otherwise stated, variables' names are a single character.  If you have multi-character variable names, you must enclose the whole name in either `$(...)` or `${...}`.

Obviously, Plan9 Makefiles may be different in that respect.

---

UPDATE:

The following `mkfile` outputs the correct value when using `mk` 2.0, `hello = qux`:

```
VAR=qux

all:
        echo "hello = bar" | sed "s/= bar/= $VAR/"
```

So the quoting in the question seems correct to me.

Comment: 1. That was a typo in my example. 2. No. I explicitly stated it uses mk(1), not make. See: http://doc.cat-v.org/plan_9/4th_edition/papers/mkfiles

Comment: @FinnO'leary I'm looking into it.

Comment: It's already solved by the quoting in my answer, I just have to wait 14 more hours to accept it. :(

Comment: Oh, interesting. Have you tried with qux=${envvar} ?